# Manual installation of Perl modules in Windows

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have tried (unsuccessfully) many times to manually install a Perl module (Win32-Printer-0.9.1) found in CPAN, but not included in the PPM repository. What I know is that the module must be downloaded and decompressed. I know you have to run the MakeFile.pl that is included.

And I know nmake is involved somehow, but despite trying to follow the directions found online, I've been unable to get it to work.

I'm using ActivePerl 5.12.2 on Windows.

I really can't figure out why this would be so complicated!

Comment: Care to mention which module this is?

Comment: This depends entirely on the module. Any using `Module::Build` are pretty trivial to install, `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`... often not.

Comment: Also, are you using Strawberry or ActiveState Perl?

Comment: Any reason not to simply use cpan?

Comment: Let me recommend Strawberry Perl, which comes packaged with the whole tool chain you need to install modules from CPAN.

Comment: First things first. Are you using ActiveState perl? What module? Is the module available through ppm (through ActiveState or another repository)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it you're using ActivePerl. It's nice, but if you need something that's not in PPM, you're sort of stuck. Take a look at the PPM configuration. By default, it only includes the ActiveState PPM site, but you can configure it to use other repositories too. Check under the Edit->Preference menu. Then click on the "Repositories" tab. There are six other PPM repositories you can include in your list of PPM repositories. Add them in, and see if your CPAN modules are in those.

The other Perl choice for Windows is [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). This includes a [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) distribution that comes with a minimally configured `gcc` compiler and base libraries. That allows you to use almost any module in the CPAN archive without modification.

Comment: ActivePerl has a proper CPAN compiler since a couple of years, very similar to Strawberry Perl: http://www.perl.com/pub/2011/08/using-cpan-on-win32-activeperl.html

Comment: @MichielB: That's nice to know. I like ActivePerl, but the lack of a compiler has been a problem. I usually had to install MinGW and do some hacking to get it to work, but decided Strawberry Perl is easier. Still, as the page you pointed out stated: _Windows does not support all POSIX features_ which might mean a few CPAN packages might not work too well. Still, the original poster is running 12.2 which should have a C compiler and is trying to download Win32:Printer. You'd think that would work.

Comment: Well, if you *download* the package - typically a .tar.gz - off CPAN you might have a hard time installing it. You normally don't have an archiver that can handle .tar.gz on Windows, and you'll need to manually install any deps. You'll only get the C-compiler when you install the 'cpan' package via PPM first. Only then you can install the module conveniently, i.e. via the CPAN client.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! I have to go to PPM, install the CPAN module, and then I get the compiler and be able to install stuff via CPAN. Apparently, you only have to point something out to me twice before it penetrates my skull. Thanks again. I'm going to install ActiveState Perl just to give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Run a command box (cmd.exe) and type 'cpan Win32::Printer' and it should install automatically.